# Bean Injection without @Autowire Annotation in spring

Tags: spring

> How to inject a class without using auto-wire annotation in spring?

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve? Don't you want auto wiring, then express your dependecies explicitly using XML or Java.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'd be interested in more details regarding "expressing dependencies in Java".

Comment: I suggest a read of the [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-bean-annotation).

Comment: And welcome to stack overflow please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways to do injection with Spring:

- Use `@Autowired` (which you don't want)
- Use `@Inject` (has most of the features as Autowired)
- Use XML configuration. This doesn't require any annotations on the classes.

Comment: You can also use `@Resource` or in xml specify the auto wiring type OR express the application context in properties files instead of XML. (Pre dates the XML stuff and was the first option for Spring :) ) or use Java based configuration. So there are more ways then you might think there are.